# C++ convert day, month and year to milliseconds

Tags: c++

I need to convert M:D:Y:H:M:S into milliseconds.

This is the function for Arduino but can't get the same in c++ for Raspberry Pi 3.

```
time_t tmConvert_t(int YYYY, byte MM, byte DD, byte hh, byte mm, byte ss)
{
  tmElements_t tmSet;
  tmSet.Year = YYYY - 1970;
  tmSet.Month = MM;
  tmSet.Day = DD;
  tmSet.Hour = hh;
  tmSet.Minute = mm;
  tmSet.Second = ss;
  return makeTime(tmSet); 
}
```

Any time I need a date converted to milliseconds I run this line.

```
unsigned long midnight = tmConvert_t(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay, 0,0,0);  // get current start of day time stamp
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to convert the time passed today into milliseconds and subtract from your `currentMillisTime `.

Comment: You described a project. What is your question according to [ask]?

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to create a variable "midnightMillis" that holds total millis since epoch from midnight. Basically when currentMillisTime hits midnight every day I want to capture the midnight timestamp in another variable.

Comment: If you know the time now since epoch and the time now since midnight, this is just a matter of subtraction, isn't it? (Also, if you know one midnight, the next is just an addition.)

Comment: Haha, I can't explain. I know time now but can't get time now since midnight.

Comment: This page shows what I'm trying to do, on right side you enter a date and time and you get the milliseconds. https://currentmillis.com/

Comment: Thanks Ted, I appreciate it!

Comment: @tryingHard I forgot about this question but found it again just now. I added an alternative that should work (if you have a c++11 compiler for the raspberry)

Answer (score 0):

You could just do what you are doing right now if you know `time_t` to be an arithmetic type holding the number of seconds passed since the epoch. A portable way could be to instead let `std::chrono` do the calculation for you.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

std::chrono::milliseconds::rep
tmConvert_t(int YYYY, int MM, int DD, int hh, int mm, int ss) {
    std::tm t{};             // initialize

    t.tm_year = YYYY - 1900;
    t.tm_mon = MM - 1;
    t.tm_mday = DD;
    t.tm_hour = hh;
    t.tm_min = mm;
    t.tm_sec = ss;
    time_t orig = std::mktime(&t);
    
    // ask for the duration since the epoch
    auto dur = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(orig).time_since_epoch();

    // cast to whole milliseconds
    auto dur_in_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(dur);

    // return the tick count in milliseconds
    return dur_in_ms.count();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << tmConvert_t(1970,01,01,0,0,0) << '\n'; // possible epoch
    std::cout << tmConvert_t(2021,02,15,0,0,0) << '\n'; // Today
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PGhac6)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but during compile it tells me "floor" and "days" are not members of "std::chrono". I don't think it should matter as I'm using the library but I'm running this on a Raspberry Pi 3.

EDIT: This wouldn't work anyways as I don't have "the_point_in_time_that_is_really_a_duration", this is what I'm trying to get.

Comment: @tryingHard Oh, ok, your compiler doesn't support the C++20 standard then (or perhaps you forgot to tell it to use it: `-std=c++20`). When you say "_current time in milliseconds is 1613216109429_" - what do you mean exactly? I thought that was a duration in relation to the epoch. If it isn't, please clarify.

Comment: In my line of code above "currentMillisTime" is 1613216109429, or at least was. That's number of milliseconds since epoch. Now I need time now since midnight so I can figure out the milliseconds at midnight.

Comment: @tryingHard Ok, I'm trying to understand what you mean by your first comment. If you add `epoch + currentMillisTime` using my answer, you get `your_point_in_time`. If you round that down (using the `chrono` cast `std::chrono::floor`) , you get the start of the day in which your _epoch + currentMillisTime_ is. - If your compiler doesn't support C++20, please specify what language standard it complies too.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately I don't know what compiler it is. This page shows what I'm trying to do though, on right side you enter a date and time and you get the milliseconds. currentmillis.com

Comment: @tryingHard Ok, then, instead of having me (and everyone else) guessing, post a [mre] and tag it with [tag:c++11]. Since you use `std::chrono` we know that it supports C++11 at least.

Comment: Thanks, if I could create a reproducible example I would be set LOL... Am I breaking rules if I answer my question with more info? I use Arduino which is a variant of c++, using time_t just create function and can import M:D:Y:H:M:S and get millis back.

Comment: "_Am I breaking rules if I answer my question with more info_" - Not at all! Sharing your own findings is encouraged since it'll help other people in the future. I'll leave my C++20 answer up though since that'll (probably) help people with C++20 compilers.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question, didn't realize I could that. It has a working example but for Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as above but works with only c++.

```
unsigned long long tmConvert_t(short YY, short MM, short DD, short hh, short mm, short ss)
{
    std::tm example;
    example.tm_sec = ss;
    example.tm_min = mm;
    example.tm_hour = hh;
    example.tm_year = YY - 1900;
    example.tm_mon = MM;
    example.tm_mday = DD;
    unsigned long long milli = std::mktime(&example);
    milli = milli * 1000;
    return milli; 
}
```

Then call this to get milliseconds since epoch.

```
unsigned long long midnightMillis = tmConvert_t(2021,01,13,0,0,00);
```

Thanks for all the help.